# The most efficient way to insert if doesn't exist else update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

similar threads are already on stackoverflow.com however none of them explains what is the most efficient way to INSERT if doesn't exist in the table or UPDATE if it does and let's assume that we want to do that with thousands of records at once and very often.

There is a table Inventory that stores ID, sku, warehouseid, quantity

I communicate with some API to get a list of all inventory (let's say in Amazon) and I want to synchronize it with my system so I always know how many quantities I have in which warehouse. Of course in some cases for new skus the query to save it in the DB would be an insert query but for ones that are old it would be an update one. What would be the most efficient way to perform this operation when we have to sync thousands of records? One more thing to add is that the combination of sku, warehouseid must be unique so when we perform an update we need to check first if that combination doesn't exist if it does we must use an insert.

Please keep in mind that for inserting records I use the multiple insert PDO (1000 inserts at once) so I can technically perform 1000 inserts within 1-2 seconds.

I was thinking about pulling all records from the Inventory table and saving them in an array. Then pulling all records from the API call and comparing them in the code. This way I would be able to specify that for example 5000 records require an update and 10000 an insert. What do you think about that? Would it be faster than performing a SELECT first and then INSERT or UPDATE? Also is there any way to perform multiple UPDATES with one query similar to as I insert records?

Here is my multiple insert function:

```
function insert_multiple($table_name, $data)
{
    $db = sitedb('','PDO');
    $sub_data = array_chunk($data, 1000);
    for ($b = 0; $b < count($sub_data); $b++)
    {
        $insert_values = array();
        for ($a = 0; $a < count($sub_data[$b]); $a++)
        {
            $insert_values = array_merge($insert_values, array_values($sub_data[$b][$a]));
            $placeholder[] = '(' . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($sub_data[$b][$a]), '?')) . ')';
        }

        $sql2    = "INSERT INTO $table_name (" . implode(",", array_keys($sub_data[$b][0])) . ") VALUES " . implode(',', $placeholder) . "";
        $prepare = $db->prepare($sql2);
        try
        {
            $prepare->execute($insert_values);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($sub_data[$b]);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo $e->getMessage();
            print_r($db->errorInfo());
        }
        unset($insert_values);
        unset($placeholder);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: in terms of efficiency you should also use `foreach` or call `count` outside of your `for` loop as right now every iteration of your loop you are calling `count` ouch!

Comment: You can consider REPLACE INTO http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 2):

```
REPLACE INTO tablename SET field1 = value1, field2 = value2;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Is there any way to pull the old value of one of the columns on update? For example if the record exist, I would like to keep the create_date value as it is.